# Dry coding with GLSL Opengl core

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-3

In my current project I render with different materials that all have their own shader, and I have portals like in the Portal game. For the portals I had to do some extra clipping. In OpenGl there is a function called glClipPlane that would work perfectly for this job. But unfortunately I have a core context, and I implemented this clipping in the fragment shader with "discard". But it required me to copy and paste the code into every material that I had written so far. So what is the correct way that does not require me to copy paste my code everywhere?

As pointed out, there is a better way to solve the clipping problem, but this problem is only an example, so please do not try to find an alternative solution for clipping.

Here is example pseudo code:

```
//shader material1
void main() {
    if( dot( plane, gl_Position ) < 0 )
        discard;

    color = light * texture(...);
}
```

other material

```
//shader material2
void main() {
    if( dot( plane, gl_Position ) < 0 )
        discard;

    color = other fancy stuff;
}
```

the point is that I have the same code in both shaders, and this bugs me.

Comment: What do you mean?Reusable shader?Then use the same shader program for the same type of material.

Comment: I made some edits. So I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Use `gl_ClipDistance [...]`. That will tell the primitive assembly stage the distance from an arbitrary set of clip planes. Pre-GL3 you would output a single clip position and during primitive assembly each plane would be tested, but in modern GL you do the distance calculation in the vertex shader and pass the result to primitive assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you do the same you would do with C code: write a function or a macro. Put the function/macro in a separate file and "include" it into your base shader (glShaderSource() can take an arbitrary number of strings; each string can be the source code of a file). With time, you'll end up with a shader library of sorts, with all of your reusable code.

Answer (score 4):

OpenGL core didn't remove user clip planes.

You enable the first one with `glEnable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE_0)` and you decide how to clip with setting `gl_ClipDistance[0]` in the vertex shader.

As to "changing all shaders", here is a potential solution: call a "potentialSetClipDistance" in *all* VS and simply implement that method in 2 different shader objects, linking against the right one depending on usage. That's the kind of things the driver does in compat GL behind your back.

Comment: wow, thanks that actually really helps me. But it doesn't answer the point of the question. It only helps in this example. And I still need to change all shader programs, just this time it is the vertex shader, not the fragment shader.

Comment: @Arne: well, yes, it doesn't answer the question, but the question was based on a false premise. It is true that the shader explosion problem is still present. I updated my answer with a potential solution.